# How to convert a dict string with value default dict to an actual dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to convert the following string to a dict:

```
"{'key1': 0, 'key2': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'total': 9, 'semcor': 9})}"
```

I tried using literal_eval from ast and also json.loads from json, however none of them can convert it. For JSON I understand that it does not have the json structure, however I don't fully understand why literal_eval doesn't work.

Can someone tell me if it is possible to do so?

Comment: Where did you get such a string? That doesn't look like anything that is *intended* to be turned back into a `dict`. `literal_eval` doesn't work because `<class 'int'>` isn't a valid Python expression.

Comment: what you show is already a dict with 2 elements

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is actually a string.

Comment: What should the keys and values of the resulting dictionary be?

Comment: I am thinking that it should look like:

{'key1': 0, 'key2': {'total': 9, 'semcor': 9}}

Comment: Serialize using pickle instead of JSON to retain the defaultdict function.

Comment: the value of key2 is defaultdict, not dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to parse it is to replace the `<class 'int'>` notation with the actual class name, and then `eval` the string:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
s = '''"{'key1': 0, 'key2': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'total': 9, 'semcor': 9})}"'''
eval(re.sub(r"<class '(\w+)'>", r'\1', s))
```

This returns:

```
{'key1': 0, 'key2': defaultdict(int, {'total': 9, 'semcor': 9})}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed